# Wireless internet is too unstable on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I'm having this issue on Ubuntu 19.10, but I also noticed in previous versions (as 19.04). I use a 5GHz Wi-Fi on my notebook, the signal arrives with medium strength (at least by looking at the icons of wi-fi).

On Ubuntu, I'm noticing a lot of instability. I just did a speed-test using fast.com and the internet went from 55Mb/s to 7.7Mb/s middle test, stayed a considerable time at 7.7-12Mb and then went right back to bigger numbers (on Windows those tests indicated a speed of around 95Mb/s).

When using Netflix or Stremio, the issue is clearer, as those services warn you when they notice you aren't connected. I receive a bunch of these warnings, as if my connection is on and off (and probably is).

I turned Power Management off, and the problem is not solved at all.

Running `iwconfig` gives me this information:

```
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"LAR_5GHz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.765 GHz  Access Point: AC:84:C6:6C:43:AF   
          Bit Rate=325 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:10   Missed beacon:0
```

Running `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Also this from Hardinfo: *MTU: 1500, Transmission Power: 22dBm (158mW), Mode: Managed, Link Quality: 48, Signal/Noise: -67dBm/-256dBm*

And running `lshw -class network`:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 30
       serial: 64:32:a8:85:f7:50
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-19-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a52a4000-a52a7fff
```

Comment: problem persists with newer kernel `5.3.16-300.fc31.x86_64` (Fedora 31)

Comment: Rebooting fixes it. I know it's not really a solution.

Comment: Me too, kernel 5.3.0-40, same driver and firmware. Bit rate jumps randomly with values from 6 MB/s to 430 MB/s